# Javascript regular expression to match number Zero OR any whole number greater than zero

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I have searched for hours but can't find this, please help. I need a Javascript regular expression to validate a text field that will contain a quantity value. The value can be zero OR any whole number greater than zero. Numbers cannot start with a zero unless they are... zero. It should not match if there is any whitespace at the start, middle or end of the quantity "string".

In other words: "0" <- Should match. "467" <- Should match. "098" <- Should not match.  "1 3" <- Should not match.

So far I have to use two Reg Exps and OR them in Javascript. It is working. Here is my code:

```
function qtyIsValid(strQty){
    var isValid;
    var reg1 = new RegExp('^0{1}$'); // <-- This matches a single ZERO and fails if any whitespace anywhere
    var reg2 = new RegExp('^[1-9]+$'); // <-- This matches any number greater than zero and fails if any whitespace anywhere

    if ( reg1.test(strQty) || reg2.test(strQty) ){
            isValid = true;
    }else{
            isValid = false;
        }
return isValid;  
}
```

But can those two Regular Expressions be combined in to one within Javascript?

Thank you.

Comment: you could use `parseInt(strQty) >= 0 && parseInt(strQty).toString() == strQty`

Comment: As implicitly said @JaromandaX, because you care about the *value* of the number you're matching, you better convert it to an integer.

Comment: I tried your suggestion in my code. Although this doesn't use Reg Exp, it is a nice solution that seems to work for my needs. It catches whitespace, non numeric characters and a number preceded by a zero. Awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this for example:

```js
r = /^(0|[1-9]\d*)$/
console.log("0".match(r));
console.log("467".match(r));
console.log("098".match(r));
console.log("1 3".match(r));
```

Comment: Thank you! This Reg Expression did exactly what I needed. I couldn't figure out how to achieve an OR in an expression but I think I understand now from your solution.

Answer (score 1):

`/^(0+|[1-9]\d*)$/` any string that is just a sequence of `0` or that contain a number not equal to 0 and not starting with `0`.

```js
console.log("0: ", /^(0+|[1-9]\d*)$/.test("0"));
console.log("000: ", /^(0+|[1-9]\d*)$/.test("000"));
console.log("055: ", /^(0+|[1-9]\d*)$/.test("055"));
console.log("123: ", /^(0+|[1-9]\d*)$/.test("123"));
console.log("1 3: ", /^(0+|[1-9]\d*)$/.test("1 3"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It doesn't work exactly as I needed because of the --> 0+ <-- I suppose it should be just --> 0 <--. I was asking for a solution that would not allow any number to be preceded by a zero and your solution allows a 00. But your solution helped me to understand Reg Exps a bit more so thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! I just thought `00...00` will be valid since it's all just zeros.